# Can i hide the Site Title area from our home page inside our sharepoint online team site's modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, master-page, modern-experience, modern-pages

I am working on an online team site collection title "Sharing", and i have created a new modern page which i set as the home page for my site. so now the home page looks as follow:-

[image]

but i am not sure if i can hide the site title area (marked in red) for my home page only? so the web page will show the "My Home Page" banner on the top of the page, instead of showing the site title and logo?

Comment: I would comment this but I dont have enough rep, but did you check in your Site Settings : Title, Description, and Logo ?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you are light years ahead of this issue by now but for others. If you want to change just that page, use a CEWP and this removes the icon and title:

```
a[class*="logoWrapper"] {
display:none !important;}

div[class*="title"] {
display:none !important;}
}
```

This removes the whole white banner on top:

```
div[class*="mainHeader"] {
display:none !important;}
}
```

There is a quality CEWP that I have used on several SharePoint Online websites. You can find it here if you want to download the sppkg file: http://www.lancebitner.com/modern-cewp.sppkg